# Make $3$ errors so CRC algorithm will result false positive

Tags: computer-science, information-theory, coding-theory

Consider the generator polynomial $100101$ and the data $1011100110001$. Applying the [CRC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) algorithm we get the transmitted message:

$$ \underbrace{1011100110001}_{Data}\,\underbrace{00011}_{Remainder}$$

I need to make $3$ errors in the transmitted word (that is, bit flips) that the receiver won't notice. Hence, the CRC algorithm will fail to notice the errors and will falsely the data.

How can this be arranged?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: In the simplest form of CRC algorithm, the *data polynomial* $d(x)$ is multiplied by $x^5$ and then divided by $x^5+x^2+1$, the CRC polynomial, to get a remainder $r(x) = x+1$ in this case.. The *transmitted word* polynomial is $x^5d(x) + x + 1$ and is a *multiple* of $x^5+x^2+1$. Can you tell why?  That's what the receiver is checking for: is the word a multiple of $x^5+x^2+1$ or not??  So, it you *add* $x^5+x^2+1$ to the transmitted word, the result will still pass the test, no?